# Android: RTP issue with H264, MediaCodec as an encoder

Tags: android, streaming, rtp, android-mediacodec, encoder

I am wrapping H264 video with RTP for network streaming.  In order to do this, I am using Android's MediaCodec configured as an encoder to generate the H264.  The RTP code is my own.

When I read the stream (using my local network to the streaming server), I can tell when the keyframe is received because the video sharpens up to what I would expect.  However, as I move my hand across the video view, I see a significant amount of pixelation until the next keyframe comes in.  My video is 960x720, 30fps and I am sending a keyframe every 2 seconds.

I can pump the raw h264 (not wrapped as RTP) from the MediaCodec encoder via a Datagram socket and play it back using ffplay.  There are no such effects when I do this.  It has to be something with the RTP encapsulation.  I verified that my stop/stop bits of the FU-A fragmentation packets are correct, as is the RTP header marker bit.  I'm sort of at a loss for what else could be the problem?